# Why compilation depends on how exception is thrown within instance initializer?

Tags: java, initializer

Why the first code snippet fails  to compile (with compile error "Initializer does not complete normally") while the second compiles fine? The only difference is in the way how the exception is thrown!

```
class CompilationFailsClass {   

   {
      // c.ERR Initializer does not complete normally
      throw new IOException();   
   }

   public CompilationFailsClass() throws IOException {
        // constructor
   }
}
```

vs

```
class CompilationOKClass {

   // with empty body effect is exactly same
   static void f() throws IOException { throw new IOException(); }

   {
      f(); // OK !
   }

   public CompilationOKClass() throws IOException {
   }
}
```

[JLS §11.2.3](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se9/html/jls-11.html#jls-11.2.3):

> It is a compile-time error if an instance variable initializer
>   (§8.3.2) or instance initializer (§8.6) of a named class can throw a
>   checked exception class, unless the named class has at least one
>   explicitly declared constructor and the exception class or one of its
>   superclasses is explicitly declared in the throws clause of each
>   constructor.

Comment: @Tom  f() throws IOException { throw new IOException(); } produces the same effect (compiles fine!). OK, I corrected the question so that it is now 100% clear.

Comment: In the first you have `throw new IOException();` in the initializer block. Shouldn't it be a part of some method?

Comment: It would be worth tidying up your question to format all the code consistently and idiomatically. It would make the whole thing easier to read.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The JLS is pretty clear about this, in [section 8.6](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se9/html/jls-8.html#jls-8.6):

> It is a compile-time error if an instance initializer cannot complete normally (§14.21).

In your first example, the instance initializer can't complete normally.

In the second example, *as far as the compiler's concerned* it can complete normally. It never *will*, but the compiler doesn't know that, therefore it's fine.

Comment: *"It is a compile-time error if an instance variable initializer (§8.3.2) or instance initializer (§8.6) of a named class can throw a checked exception class, unless the named class has at least one explicitly declared constructor and the exception class or one of its superclasses is explicitly declared in the throws clause of each constructor."* - JLS is contradicting itself. The same issue has been discussed on coderanch several years ago: https://coderanch.com/t/323675/java/Exception-Handling-Instance-Initializer-Blocks

Comment: @Tom: I don't see where there's a contradiction. There's a big difference between "an instance initializer *can* throw a checked exception" and "the compiler can tell that there is no way for the instance initializer to complete normally". The first of these is covered in the second example - the instance initializer calls `f` which is declared to potentially throw `IOException`, but that's okay because the constructor is also declared to throw `IOException`.

Comment: Then it is misleading, because OPs second version does throw the exception, just wrapped in a "proxy method". There is no clear distinction in the JLS regarding exceptions directly thrown in the initializer block and the ones thrown in methods called by the initializer block. The block doesn't complete normally in both cases.

Comment: @Tom: I don't see that it's misleading at all. You just need to understand what "cannot complete normally" means, which is explained in chapter 14. The difference between "something that we know can't happen" and "something that provably can't happen as far as the compiler is concerned" is common throughout language specifications.